# Using a single form to handle several tasks

Tags: vb.net

I am having a hard time explaining what I am trying to do, so googling my answer was not working.

I have a Windows form I am using as a msgbox. I have 10 buttons that I want to all go to the form Shutdownbox, but each 1 of the 10 buttons needs to change a piece of the Command string. Only way I can think of is 10 different forms for this... but there has to be a better way.

Example: 
ShutdownButton1 clicked, puts REMOTEPC1.Text into the field. Or if button 2, do remotePC2, ect.

Code:

```
Public Class ShutdownBox

Private Sub shutdown_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles shutdown.Click
    Dim command As String = "/C ""net use \\" & REMOTEPC1.Text & "\IPC$ PASSWORD /USER:DOMAIN\USERNAME& shutdown /s /f /t 01 /m \\" & REMOTEPC1.Text & "\"""

    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Shutdown?", "Power Down", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.No Then
        Exit Sub
        Me.Close()
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Process.Start("cmd", command)
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Once again, sorry, its hard to explain.

EDIT:
Picture to try and help
[image]

Comment: Have the buttons' click event handlers set variables.  Pretty unlikely you should be using just buttons btw, you must provide feedback to the user when you have that many of them.  Unless they are RadioButtons.  Throw some labels at it and it gets simple in your code as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you give me an example of how it sets a variable for it please?

Comment: When I click one of the shutdown buttons it does the ShutdownBox.show()

Comment: instead of 10 forms and 10 forms, why not a combobox with 10 items and let them pick from that and your code acts on it

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your goals. When you say you're using the form as a msgbox, what _exactly_ do you mean? Also, do you mean that there should be ten visible buttons at all times? Is that shutdown_Click sub the only thing i your ShutdownBox class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First form...

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
        Form2.Text = TextBox1.Text
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox6.Click
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        TextBox2.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox2.BackColor = Color.White
        Form2.Text = TextBox2.Text
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox9.Click
    If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        TextBox3.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox3.BackColor = Color.White
        Form2.Text = TextBox3.Text
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox12.Click
    If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
        TextBox4.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox4.BackColor = Color.White
        Form2.Text = TextBox4.Text
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox15.Click
    If TextBox5.Text = "" Then
        TextBox5.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox5.BackColor = Color.White
        Form2.Text = TextBox5.Text
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox18_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox18.Click
    If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
        TextBox6.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox6.BackColor = Color.White
        Form2.Text = TextBox6.Text
        Form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Add a second form...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Process.Start("cmd", "/C ""net use \\" & Me.Text & "\IPC$ PASSWORD /USER:DOMAIN\USERNAME& shutdown /r /f /t 01 /m \\" & Me.Text & "\""")
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Process.Start("cmd", "/C ""net use \\" & Me.Text & "\IPC$ PASSWORD /USER:DOMAIN\USERNAME& shutdown /s /f /t 01 /m \\" & Me.Text & "\""")
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

this time no need to save strings in app's settings...

Comment: Ah I see how you did it, its so simple!The, Form2.text = Textbox.text.

Comment: this will change the title of the form 2... if you dont want it to change you can use a label in form 2 and modify that instead of the forms title... and thwn you can hide the label...

Answer (score 3):

I personally would use My.Settings.. have all the commands needed to be sent and call them from click event handler... I quickly wrote this, I hope it helps.

[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Shutdown?", "Power Down", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Process.Start("cmd", My.Settings.command1)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox6.Click
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        TextBox2.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox2.BackColor = Color.White
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Shutdown?", "Power Down", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Process.Start("cmd", My.Settings.command2)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox9.Click
    If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        TextBox3.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox3.BackColor = Color.White
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Shutdown?", "Power Down", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Process.Start("cmd", My.Settings.command3)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox12.Click
    If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
        TextBox4.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox4.BackColor = Color.White
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Shutdown?", "Power Down", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Process.Start("cmd", My.Settings.command4)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox15.Click
    If TextBox5.Text = "" Then
        TextBox5.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox5.BackColor = Color.White
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Shutdown?", "Power Down", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Process.Start("cmd", My.Settings.command5)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox18_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox18.Click
    If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
        TextBox6.BackColor = Color.Tomato
    Else
        TextBox6.BackColor = Color.White
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Shutdown?", "Power Down", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Exit Sub
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Process.Start("cmd", My.Settings.command6)
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, thats almost exactly what I need., but I would like the option for restart also. Any ideas for that?

Comment: I'd make that one sub that handles the click-event for all six PBs and then looks the command up based on the sender.